# A more efficient solution for balanced split of an array with additional conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization, time-complexity

I appreciate your help in advance. This is a practice question from Meta's interview preparation website. I have solved it, but I wonder if any optimization can be done.

##### Question:

Is there a way to solve the following problem with a time complexity of O(n)?

##### Problem Description:

> You have been given an array nums of type int. Write a program that
> returns the bool type as the return value of the solution function to
> determine whether it is possible to split nums into two arrays A and B
> such that the following two conditions are satisfied.
>
> 1. The sum of the respective array elements of A and B is equal.
> 2. All the array elements in A are strictly smaller than all the array elements in B.

##### Examples:

> nums = [1,5,7,1] -> true since A = [1,1,5], B = [7]
>
> nums = [12,7,6,7,6] -> false since A = [6,6,7], B = [7,12] failed the 2nd
> requirement

##### What I have tried:

I have used the sort function in Python, which has a time complexity of O(nlog(n)).

```
from typing import List



def solution(nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    total_sum = sum(nums)

    # If the total sum of the array is 0 or an odd number, 
    # it is impossible to have array A and array B equal.
    if total_sum % 2 or total_sum == 0:
        return False

    nums.sort()

    curr_sum, i = total_sum, 0

    while curr_sum > total_sum // 2:
        curr_sum -= nums[i]
        i += 1

    if curr_sum == total_sum // 2 and nums[i] != nums[i - 1]:
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: Is this online somewhere for testing?

Comment: It's from meta's interview preparation site.

Comment: I'd say before optimizing, make sure it's correct. It isn't. For example, `solution([])` returns `False`.

Comment: This is the correct solution by the way (as it passed all test cases which includes ```nums = []``` in meta's interview prep site)

Comment: But you can split it into `A = []` and `B = []`, which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: You could use a max-heap. However, in my understanding, it is still O(n logn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, you can modify QuickSelect to get a with-high-probability and expected O(n)-time algorithm, though Python's sort is so fast that it hardly seems like a good idea. Deterministic O(n) is possible and left as an easy exercise to the reader familiar with selection algorithms (but the constant factor is even worse, so...).

```py
import random


def can_partition(nums, a_sum=0, b_sum=0):
    if not nums:
        # True makes more sense here, but whatever
        return False
    pivot = random.choice(nums)
    less = sum(n for n in nums if n < pivot)
    equal = sum(n for n in nums if n == pivot)
    greater = sum(n for n in nums if n > pivot)
    a_ext = a_sum + less
    b_ext = greater + b_sum
    if abs(a_ext - b_ext) == equal:
        return True
    elif a_ext < b_ext:
        return can_partition([n for n in nums if n > pivot], a_ext + equal, b_sum)
    else:
        return can_partition([n for n in nums if n < pivot], a_sum, equal + b_ext)


print(can_partition([1, 5, 7, 1]))
print(can_partition([12, 7, 6, 7, 6]))
```